# Styled-components: media queries with min-width 768px gets applied at 300px width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

So I am working on this page where clients can start a request. Underneath you see the design (mobile-first) how it will look on a desktop and on mobile. I made this page in React with styled components

Now, I have problems making the mobile version appear because my media queries for the tablets (min-width: 768px) overwrite the styling at 320px width. I have been looking around and found suggested solutions like adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

to my HTML, but it doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone know what might cause this strange behaviour?

**Example of styled component (on images below circled in blue)**

```
const FirstLine = styled.div`
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
font-family: inherit;

@media (min-width: 768px) {
flex-direction: row;
}
`;
```

**example of problem: width is 300px and the mediaquery of min-width=768px is still applied: (styled component firstLine is circled in blue and still has flex-direction: row instead of column**

edit: it might be confusing, but this is an example of one of the queries being applied at 320px, not that of the Firstline styled component specifically. Sorry if it caused confusion.

[image]

**example of what mobile design should look like**

[image]

Comment: Please provide your HTML also or jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: It's too big of a complex file to put it in a jsFiddle

Comment: Try to reverse the query.That means, initially use flex-direction:row; and use flex-direction:column!important; inside @media (max-width:768px).